# RegEx match with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string.match condition that was working until I realized that some words are "*personal(computer)*" have special characters like parentheses in the word. For example my code is grabbing the term to compare to which would be "personal(computer)" and searching through data to find any instance of that, but by using

```
string1.match(stringtarget,"ig"); //returns null
```

I am a novice with regex, so how could I fix this to work for special characters as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the regular expression features, you can use `indexOf`:

```
if (string1.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringtarget.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    // It's in there
}
```

Otherwise (and I'm guessing you're using `match` for a reason!), you'll have to pre-process the `stringtarget` to escape any special characters.

For instance, this is a function I used in a recent project to do exactly that, which is inspired by a similar PHP function:

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    (function() {
        // This is drawn from http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote:491
        RegExp.escape = RegExp_escape;
        function RegExp_escape(str) {
            return String(str).replace(/([\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!<>\|\:])/g, '\\$1');
        }
    })();
}
```

And so:

```
var match = string1.match(RegExp.escape(stringtarget),"ig");
```

Comment: I can't pre-process the stringtarget to escape special characters, because then I would have to do it for every piece of data I'm comparing it to, and was trying to avoid from doing that

Comment: @Jake: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can't avoid it. If you want to use a string that may contain anything as the source of a regular expression, you *must* escape special characters in that string first. Note that this only applies to the string defining the regex, not the strings you're matching against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`preg_quote` javascript port](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote:491) to escape regex-specific characters.