# Regex match with special character

Tags: php, regex

I'm having the following reg-ex which is working fine for the normal string match against an array,

```
preg_grep( "/^". $name . "$/i", $values);
```

However its not working for the string which has special characters like "Entertainment (General)".

Find a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155910/regex-match-with-special-characters) however its for java script and also it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) function to escape any special characters that might be in the string:

```
preg_grep( "/^". preg_quote($name, '/') . "$/i", $values);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/preg_quote):

> `preg_quote()` puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.

Comment: Ah. how I missed that functio? :(. Thanks for the very quick response :)